# PHCachingImageManager returns NSError for iCloud images

Tags: ios, caching, photosframework

I have an app in which I retrieve and display images from the iDevice. I use the following code:

```
PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];
options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeNone;
options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
options.networkAccessAllowed = YES;

PHCachingImageManager *manager = [[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init];
[manager requestImageForAsset:asset
                   targetSize:CGSizeMake(asset.pixelHeight, asset.pixelWidth)
                  contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit
                      options:options
                resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                   // Do something with the result
                }];
```

My problem is that when the image I am trying to retrieve is not on the user's device, but only on iCloud (Settings -> iCloud -> Photos -> Optimise iPhone Storage), the requestImageForAsset: returns nil as result and the following NSError:

```
NSError *   domain: @"NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 18446744073709551615
```

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHCachingImageManager_Class/index.html) for PHCachingImageManager says that:

> When you need an image for an individual asset, call the
>   requestImageForAsset:targetSize:contentMode:options:resultHandler:
>   method, and pass the same parameters you used when preparing that
>   asset.
>
> **If the image you request is among those already prepared, the
>   PHCachingImageManager object immediately returns that image.
>   Otherwise, Photos prepares the image on demand and caches it for later
>   use.**

So in theory my code should work. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: I'm getting the same error when attempting to retrieve live photos saved to the documents directory